# get mysql records when following a user

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

```
[TABLE1]

+----------+-------------------+
| USERNAME | POST              |
+----------+-------------------+
| Bob      | 'Hi There'        |
| Jack     | 'Hello'           |
| Bob      | 'Today is Monday' |
+----------+-------------------+


[TABLE2]

+----------+-----------+
| USERNAME | FOLLOWING |
+----------+-----------+
| Mike     | Jack      |
| Jack     | Bob       |
| Bob      | Jack      |
| Jack     | Mike      |
+----------+-----------+
```

I know how to join two tables when you want one row.. but what about when you want to work out the below?

```
Select * from TABLE1 when TABLE1.USERNAME IS A USERNAME JACK is FOLLOWING;
```

Comment: If I got this right, you want to pull records from table 1 only if the user in table 1 is following someone?

Comment: let's say my name is JACK, i only want to show posts from people i am following.

Comment: `when TABLE1.USERNAME IS A USERNAME JACK is FOLLOWING` Funny... I think you should start reading mysql tutorials..

Comment: Have a look at the manual for `JOIN`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html

Answer (score 4):

For Username Jack is following :

```
select TABLE1.USERNAME, TABLE1.POST 
from TABLE1, TABLE2
where 
     TABLE1.USERNAME = TABLE2.FOLLOWING 
     and
     TABLE2.USERNAME = "Jack"
```

For the Username who is following Jack

```
select TABLE1.USERNAME, TABLE1.POST 
from TABLE1, TABLE2
where 
     TABLE1.USERNAME = TABLE2.USERNAME 
     and
     TABLE2.FOLLOWING = "JACK"
```

Comment: Wouldn't `TABLE2.FOLLOWING = "JACK"` mean those following Jack? OP is asking for people who Jack is following.

Answer (score 0):

TRY ( assume PHP )

```
$username - 'Jack';
"SELECT t1.* FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.username = t2.username AND t2.following = '".$username."' ";
```

**NOTE :** is both table's column name are same then you can use `USING(username)` instead of `ON` condition

Comment: *. ON t1.username = t2.username .*

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t2.username = 'Jack'
AND t1.username = t2.following
```